# Moments of the shifted log-normal

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm curious to see if there are any closed-form solutions for the moments of a shifted log-normal distribution. That is, if

$$Y\sim \log\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2),$$ I'm wondering about evaluating

$$\mathbb{E}\big[(Y-c)^\alpha \mathbb{1}_{Y>c}\big] = \int_{c}^\infty \frac{(y-c)^\alpha}{y\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(\log(y)-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}d y,$$ for some arbitrary $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

Anyone have any idea? I've tried expanding the term $(Y-c)^\alpha$ into a binomial series, which converges for a.e. Y since we assume $Y\geq c$, but the output is messy and doesn't seem to admit a nice closed-form solution.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156277/shifted-log-normal-distribution-and-moments

Comment: No one has provided a better answer than the binmial solution yet!

Comment: The first partial moment of this is a call option price under the black scholes model, and the result will be in terms of normal CDF. I guess the higher moments will be similar, and as you said it may looks a little bit messy.