# Shifted log normal power expectancy

Tags: probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I want to come back on an old post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727985/moments-of-the-shifted-log-normal).

Can someone compute $E(Y^{\alpha})$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ where $Y$ follows a shifted log normal distribution? I saw [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156277/shifted-log-normal-distribution-and-moments) for the case where $\alpha$ is an integer number. I search for the general case with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.